# Share all files between all admin users on Mac OSX Catalina

Tags: macos, mac, permissions, file-permissions

I'm using a Mac running Catalina, and I have several users set up to do different things. ALL THE USERS ARE ME - I just want different desktops for work, home and one other with music apps.

I want to be able to access any file anywhere on any drive volume from any of my 3 users. All three of my users are administrators.

I cannot share my root hard drive volumes or even folders within them read/write with all three users. I'm plagued by "insufficient permissions" messages when try to save files around the drive.

How do I enable access to the whole drive for my admin users (without making them publicly available to anyone connecting to my laptop on a network, of course)? Thanks.

Comment: Anything saved outside the Users folders [or in Users/Shared] should be accessible to any user. There's no need to 'share' anything, that's for remote users.

Answer (score 1):

**PLEASE TEST THIS ON ANOTHER FOLDER FIRST!**

If you want all of your acct's to have access to each other's "home" folders, go to the Users folder, Get Info, hit the Unlock icon at the bottom right, hit the "+" button at the bottom left, find the Admininstrators group:

[image: admins]

Press Select there, then back to the Get Info window, change the permission from **Read only** to **Read & Write**:

[image: RW]

Then here's the trick, press the Gear icon and choose "Apply to Enclosed Items", so it applies recursively.

I say to test this first because it's possible that Get Info will apply those *exact* permissions to all of the items in the folder you selected, overriding any things that are different (like each user being explicitly listed for RW access to its own home folder).  I would hope Get Info would just apply the additional permissions, and not remove the original permissions, but PLEASE TEST FIRST, like on the Shared folder or somewhere that each user has added files/folders.

Since each user is a member of the Admins, this won't remove any effective access, but it would be weird to not have the user's name explicitly in the access list of its own home dir.